# how to sort array of strings in php ? [here strings are the path. e.g. /root/mandy/a.pdf, b.pdf & c.pdf

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

how to sort array of strings in php? Here strings are the paths. e.g. `/root/mandy/a.pdf, b.pdf & c.pdf etc`.

I tried with `sort()` function with it's parameters, however it's not working ?

**EDIT (based on OP's comments):**

My bad ! I haven't posted this question correctly. Apologies...

Actually it's an array of maps `[not sure may be array of array] -> array("path => "file_name")` & i need to sort it accordingly the `file_name`.

Comment: What result did you get from `sort` and how does it differ from the one you expected?

Comment: You should show your code and tell us what's the exact problem (other than `not working`). `sort()` should do it, based on your description.

Comment: What was your problem with my answer? You previously accepted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$strings = array('/root/mandy/c.pdf', '/root/mandy/a.pdf', '/root/mandy/b.pdf');
sort($strings);
print_r($strings);
```

It works for me.

Comment: My bad ! I haven't posted this question correctly.apologies...Actually it's an array of maps [not sure may be array of array]  -> array("path => "file_name") & i need to sort it accordingly the file_name.

Comment: @mandy You can `edit` more information into your answer any time.

Answer (score 7):

Or even better, use **strcmp** to compare the strings

```
uasort($yourArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['path'], $b['path']);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on your updates.

You could try using [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), which lets you define a comparison function and also maintains index association (not sure if you need it, use `usort()` if you don't).

I've written the comparison function here as a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), which is available since PHP 5.3. In earlier versions, you can create a normal function and use its name as a string in the second parameter of `uasort()`.

```
uasort($yourArray, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['path']==$b['path']) return 0;
    return $a['path']>$b['path'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

You can change `path` to anything that matches the key of your filenames, I just made an assumption based on your comment.

Comment: Attention this may be depricated in PHP 8: https://lindevs.com/sort-comparison-functions-that-return-boolean-value-is-deprecated-in-php-8-0/